# Facebook multiple IDs for the same user

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i just noticed the same user can have different facebook ids. This situation happens when a user change its own name, for example:

Johann Gomes B. Lima (https://www.facebook.com/993673107328394) changed its own Facebook Name to... Johann Gomes (https://www.facebook.com/100000571429851).

This name change (and subsequently id change) happened two weeks ago, there is a possibility this is a delay in Facebook Graph API data, and only one ID will be returned in the next days?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Name changes doesn't trigger id changes. What you are experience are app scoped user ids. You can read about it here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading

Comment: I'm not geting the ID through different apps, i'm just crawling users public links and IDs of people who comments there.

Comment: So how did you get the first id and how did you get the second id? Could it be that the user logged in to your app between the first and second time